# Drupal put more values in #markup $form type

Tags: media, theming

Is it possible to add more values into the #markup of a drupal form?

At the moment it is a link but I also want to add an image. When I add another #markup it only takes the last one, and when I add $image to the other #markup it doesn't work.

My code:

```
$image_options = array(
    'path' => 'img_url',
    'alt' => 'App logo',
    'title' => 'App logo',
    'width' => '56px',
    'height' => '56px',
    'attributes' => array('class' => 'some-img', 'id' => 'my-img'),
);

$image = theme('image', $image_options);

$form["link$key"] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#description' => t('Registered token(s): @total_tokens <br> Total sent push notifications: @push_notifications', array('@appname' => $record->app_name, '@total_tokens' => $total_tokens, '@push_notifications' => $sentMessages)),
  // '#href' => "admin/config/services/push_notifications/stats/". $record->app_id,
  '#markup' => l($record->app_name, 'admin/config/services/push_notifications/stats/' . $record->app_id),
);
```

So I want to be able to add $image to the current #markup..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The #markup property simply provides a string output.

Why dont you just concatenate your output into a variable.

```
$output = $image;
$output .= $link;
```

Then...

```
'#markup' => $output
```

Checkout the coding standards for Drupal around concatenation.
https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards#concat